# Why can't Groovy regex matchers be negated?

Tags: regex, syntax, groovy

Can anyone explain the following?

```
println('x' ==~ /x/)
println('x' !=~ /x/)
```

result:

```
true
true
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no `!=~` operator in groovy. It's a combination of `!=` and `~`.

```
println('x' !=~ /x/)
```

is equivalent to

```
println('x' != (~ /x/))
```

What you need is

```
println(!('x' ==~ /x/))
```

Comment: Weird!  What's `(~ /x/)` mean?  I worked out !(...), but still found this surprising.

Comment: Technically `/x/` is just a string, `~ /x/` is the pattern built by this string. Try evaluating `/x/.class` and `(~/x/).class` in groovy console.