# How to check if a String matches a pattern in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

How do I check if a string matches a pattern in groovy? My pattern is "somedata:somedata:somedata", and I want to check if this string format is followed. Basically, the colon is the separator.

Answer (score 45):

Groovy regular expressions have a `==~` operator which will determine if your string matches a given regular expression pattern.

### Example

```
// ==~ tests, if String matches the pattern
assert "2009" ==~ /\d+/  // returns TRUE
assert "holla" ==~ /\d+/ // returns FALSE
```

Using this, you could create a regex matcher for your sample data like so:

```
// match 'somedata', followed by 0-N instances of ':somedata'...
String regex = /^somedata(:somedata)*$/

// assert matches...
assert "somedata" ==~ regex
assert "somedata:somedata" ==~ regex
assert "somedata:somedata:somedata" ==~ regex

// assert not matches...
assert "somedata:xxxxxx:somedata" !=~ regex
assert "somedata;somedata;somedata" !=~ regex
```

### Read more about it here:

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_match_operator

Comment: The old groovy.codehouse.org site is expired. Try this: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_regular_expression_operators

Comment: The 'assert not matches' examples should look like this: `assert !("somedata:xxxxxxxx:somedata" ==~ regex)`.   `!=~` is not a valid operator to negate a regex match: https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_regular_expression_operators

Comment: @Joman68 - just tried it over here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_groovy_online.php (Groovy 2.4.8) - code works fine. Have you tried it? Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @NickGrealy reproducible example here: https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5129310184669184

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19858242/3059685 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/31220106/3059685

Answer (score 5):

The negate regex match in Groovy should be

```
 String regex = /^somedata(:somedata)*$/   
 assert !('somedata;somedata;somedata' ==~ regex)  // assert success!
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using a regular expression like `.+:.+:.+`.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher
import java.util.regex.Pattern

def match = "somedata:somedata:somedata" ==~ /.+:.+:.+/
```

Answer (score -5):

Was able to resolve this using:

myString.matches("\S+:\S+:\S+")

Comment: Asks for help. Doesn't use suggestions. A+