# How to negate the Groovy Match Operator?

Tags: regex, groovy

The [documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_regular_expression_operators) mentions three regex specific operators:

- `~` returning a `Pattern`
- `=~` returing a `Matcher`
- `==~` returning a `boolean`

Now, how can I negate the last one? (I agree that the others can't have any meaningful negation.)

I tried the obvious thinking:

```java
println 'ab' ==~ /^a.*/ // true: yay, matches, let's change the input
println 'bb' ==~ /^a.*/ // false: of course it doesn't match, let's negate the operator
println 'bb' !=~ /^a.*/ // true: yay, doesn't match, let change the input again
println 'ab' !=~ /^a.*/ // true: ... ???
```

I guess the last two should be interpreted like this rather:

```
println 'abc' != ~/^b.*/
```

where I can see `new String("abc") != new Pattern("^b.*")` being `true`.

Comment: it's about an operator that does this and `!(...)` is no option?

Comment: I don't know if there is a "not match" operator, but you can always negate the result like this: `println !('abc' ==~ /^a.*/)`

Comment: It would be nice if there was a concise way, but if not, that's an obvious answer :( I just expected more I guess, like Perl has `!~`.

Comment: fell into the same trap (if such it be).  But "!=~" shouldn't be able to be interpreted as "equivalent" to "!= ~" ! ... white space is usually one of the main factors in syntax parsing in just about every computer language!  IMHO it should throw a compile/scripting error.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no negated regular expression match operator in Groovy.

So - as already mentioned by cfrick - it seems that the best answer is to negate the whole expression:

```
println !('bb' ==~ /^a.*/)
```

Another solution is to invert the regular expression, but it seems to me to be less readable:

[How can I invert a regular expression in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538512/how-can-i-invert-a-regular-expression-in-javascript)